# Speech to Text API with Unknown Language

Tags: natural-language-processing

I would like to develop an application that outputs text from the audio of 2 possible languages.

For ex: Audio might be English or Spanish, it should return the spoken words.

Most speech to text APIs strongly rely on an input language for words retrieval, I would like to know if there's any tool or research paper that could work for my use case.

Comment: Try both languages, and pick the one for which text-to-speech seems to work better. (Presumably a text-to-speech engine can return a score expressing how well it understood its input.)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Are you aware of any text-to-speech engine with confidence rate scope?

Comment: I'm completely ignorant of this subject, unfortunately. It is also possible you'd have to hack the engine, or perhaps pass the output through some statistical test instead.